# ARCore World Alignment

Tags: java, arkit, arcore

Is there an option similar to the ARKit's WorldAlignment for ARCore to change from Camera to Gravity and Heading? or do I need to change the location of each object accordingly?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I used the suggested answer idea and made my objects be childs of my empty world object and used heading/compass data to manipulate the orientation.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

ARCore only supports case Gravity. The origin is always the initial position of your device with a left-handed coordinate system as +y is the upwards direction.

You can always create and anchor an object and put all your content as a child to this object if you want to change coordinate system. Then you can work in local space and for example have z axis as upwards depending on initial object rotation.

Therefore, with a little bit of coding you can achieve case gravityAndHeading and case camera.

Comment: thanks for the answer and suggestion. I'll try and do that. I want the axis to be the way they are, but just rotate around the y axis so that it looks depending on the heading.